# JavaScript/jQuery - Intercepting for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a website and a script with a `for` loop which uses the variable (`i`);

So, the loop looks like this:

```
var i;
for(i=start_n;i<=end_n;i++){
//function to execute
}
```

So, I need a function which can intercept `for` loop and stop it immediately when a 'Stop' button is clicked.

I tried the following functions:

1st:

```
$('#btnStop').click(function(){
i=end_n;
});
```

2nd:

```
$('#btnStop').click(function(){
stopLoading = true;
});

for(i=start_n;i<=end_n;i++){
if(stopLoading==true){break;}
//function to execute
}
```

Neither of them worked. So, is there any way to intercept that for loop and stop it?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded... if the loop is running, it is running, you cannot stop it. You could create a queue of tasks and process it asynchronously with `setTimeout` though.

Comment: The only way you could possibly stop it is if you put the loop body in a `setTimeout` callback, which might require significant refactoring. (EDIT: Felix beat me to it in his edit!)

Comment: I think you could set a global variable and test it inside of the loop. so the button sets myobj.foo = false and your loop could check if (myobj.foo === false) { break; } or similar. So, it would loop until your i ran out or the click could break it, too, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setInterval instead of for loop ?

Ex.:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ /*do something many times*/}, 99);
$('#stop').click(function(){ clearInterval(interval); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't interrupt JS from being executed. The best you can do is have the loop running inside a `setInterval`, and having the button clear that interval, but the disadvantage is that the page has to redraw between every iteration so at best you'll get 60 iterations per second, as opposed to the millions you can get away with normally.

Answer (score 1):

For loops are blocking and concurrent, you can 'simulate' this by instead of using a for loop using some sort of timeout that runs let's say every 10 miliseconds. However this would not really be accomplishing the same thing.

Like the comment said, javascript (on the browser) is single threaded so once you're in the for loop nothing else will happen until that for loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this the want you want but you can interrupt the loop with a bit of overhead.  For example, each time around the loop you could do a database request (ajax) to check if the loop should be interrupted or not.
Then you could have a button which sets the "should interrupt" value checked by the loop.

Still, I'm not sure this will work as intended...